# Add options to a Wordpress plugin Custom Post Type via child theme functions.php

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, custom-post-type

I'm using **Uncode** theme for a site. It has a core custom post type called 'portfolio'.

I need to add an option to this CPT so that it shares the tags with regular posts.

I have found the file in the theme core where the CPT is registered and added the following and it works:

```
'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category', 'post_tag')
```

However, as editing core files is a big no no, I'm wondering if there is a way of doing this through my own functions file so it is future proof?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: It's apparent that I've misunderstood!

Looks like `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` is what you're after.

The [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) has this to say:

> ### register_taxonomy_for_object_type()
>
> Add a registered Taxonomy to a registered Post Type.

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'post_tag', 'portfolio' );
```

---

Original answer:

From the [WP Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type):

> ### register_post_type()
>
> Create ***or modify*** a post type. **`register_post_type`** should only be invoked through the `'init'` action. It will not work if called before `'init'`, and aspects of the newly created or modified post type will work incorrectly if called later.

<sub>*(addtl. emphasis mine)*</sub>

This being the case, you could create a function

```
function igloobob_portfolio_cpt_mod() {
    register_post_type('portfolio', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'igloobob_portfolio_cpt_mod', 999);
```

where `$args` basically duplicate's the **Uncode** theme's arguments to `register_post_type`, save for your modification. The `999` priority arg is to ensure that it executes after the parent theme has already registered the post type.

Comment: that sound sperfect Cameron thanks. If I did that, would it affect all the posts already in under the parent theme CPT or would everything remain? ie would they all be suddenly missing and I'd need to re create them.

Comment: @igloobob - your posts and their metadata would remain untouched! (Btw, great username)

Comment: sorry for delayed replay, just looking at this, so if I was to add my new argument to that function, is this how I would do it?

‘function igloobob_portfolio_cpt_mod() {
    register_post_type('portfolio', $args),
    'taxonomies' => array('portfolio_category', 'post_tag');
}
add_action('init', 'igloobob_portfolio_cpt_mod', 999);’

Comment: Updated my answer, after reading the question and your comments through again!